# In Apache Spark Scala, how to fill Vectors.dense in DataFrame from CSV?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

world,

I am new to spark.

I noticed this online example:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html

I am curious about this syntax:

```
// Prepare training data from a list of (label, features) tuples.
val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
)).toDF("label", "features")
```

Is it possible to replace the above call to some syntax which reads values from CSV?

I want something comparable to Python-Pandas read_csv() method.

Comment: Yes and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @eliasah Not so much. `VectorUDT` cannot be directly represented in csv, can it?

Comment: @zero323 It can't be directly represented, but it's easy to do it. But I was wondering if the OP has tried something or if he's just looking for someone to do his job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: Yes, it is possible

If the CSV is on HDFS, you can use spark-csv to read it: [example](http://www.sparktutorials.net/opening-csv-files-in-apache-spark---the-spark-data-sources-api-and-spark-csv), or of its on the normal filesystem you can just read if with plain scala : [example](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch12s06.html)

Comment: Is there an example that is not behind a registration wall?